# Postgres: Copying particular tables from remote db, interrelated with foreign key relationships

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pg-dump

I have a Postgres RDS instance for one of my apps.
I need to copy 3 tables from it to a similar clone of the database.

I see mytable_id_seq tables also, which now I know are called sequences in postgres terminology.

When I created a dump of those three tables, and restore them, do I have to do anything with the _id_seq sequences ?

Do I have to restore them too, for the dump data to work as it did in the original table?

Answer (score 0):

When you restore the entire database from a dump, it contains CREATE SEQUENCE statements by default. These statements initialize sequences to the proper state. But if you make a partial dump, with only selected tables, you must set sequences manualy.
Assuming, that your table's name is "clip", you can check the current value using this query:

> SELECT last_value FROM clip_id_seq

And if you want to update the sequence after restore, you can do it with this simple query:

> SELECT SETVAL('clip_id_seq', SELECT MAX(id) FROM clip)

Answer (score 0):

```
pg_dump -d database_name -t mg_cnd  -F c > database_backup.sql
pg_restore -U database_user --data-only -d database_name -t mg_cnd -F c <file_location>
```

- -d = database name
- -t = table name
- -F = Format 
  c = plain
- -U = User
- --data-only = transfer only table data

[pg_dump documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html)

[pg_restore documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-pgrestore.html)